# Is there a way to create a Schema-Type based on a Package-Type (ojdbc6 driver is not able to access packaged types)

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm currently writing a Java wrapper for a PL-SQL Api. I created Java classes implementing SqlData for each defined type. Then I created a Java service class and tried to call one PL-SQL function through SimpleJdbcCall which returns one of these types.

I got following error message: `error code [17074]; invalid name pattern:`

After some investigation I realized that it is not possible to access types defined within packages through JDBC on Oracle 11g. This will be possible after switching to Oracle 12.

see here http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/apxref.htm#JJDBC29032

Now my question:

> Is there a way to create a schema type based on a package type. Or is
>   there a way to create a Package-Type based on a Schema-Type? Both ways should work without further implications on other programs/databases/systems.

Problem is, that this database schema and its package types are already being used by other users. Just moving the package types to the schema level would result into lots of other PL-SQL code changes.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no way. Even if you create identical types they are not the same type from PL/SQL point of view. Let's see if anyone else comes up with ideas. I think you have to add an extra PL/SQL API (a facade or an adapter) that wraps the current PL/SQL API inside a more Java friendly PL/SQL API. I can give you an example later if you didn't get the point.

Comment: Thanks user272735 ;) I tried first creating an identical type. I got your poing but would be happy to see an example for such a wrapper.

Comment: It is not only a JDBC Problem - it is the same for simple SQL-Statements. You cannot use Package-Types in SQL-Select Statements, only schema-types. But I think there was a way to cast them to identical schema types...

Comment: i also think so, that's it's not a jdbc problem. otherwise oracle would not say in the 12c documentation that since 12c also schema_types can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Anwer to this solution is, that there is no way to create schema types based on package types on 11g.

I've redefined now the package record types as schema object types and I'm in the process to create a pl-sql package which works with my schema-types, wraps/unwraps them and delegates the procedure/function calls.

I named the schema objects same as the package records so after a update to oracle12 i only have to set a package-name prefix.
I also wrapper package _wrapper so I only have to remove the "_wrapper" part to be able to use the original_package after migrating to 12c.

> My conclusion is: Don't use package types. Object types are more flexible.